# Как работает алгоритм сжатия в TGA изображении?

Tags: c++, изображения, сжатие, rle

Я хочу научиться читать изображения различных форматов в массив байтов. Для меня это достаточно сложная задача, поэтому я начал с наиболее простых форматов. С PPM P6 проблем не возникло, но, когда я решил разобраться с TGA изображениями, столкнулся с некоторыми вещами, которым пока не могу найти объяснение. Например, я не понимаю принцип работы алгоритма сжатия, который использует данный формат.

В интернете можно найти спецификацию для TGA 2. Насколько я понял, формат TGA 2 не меняет основные принципы обычного TGA, а только добавляет некоторые данные в конец файла, поэтому алгоритмы сжатия и упорядочивания последовательности цветов пикселей изображения не должны меняться. Спецификацию можно почитать здесь: [https://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~martino/disciplinas/ea978/tgaffs.pdf](https://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/%7Emartino/disciplinas/ea978/tgaffs.pdf) или здесь:
http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/tga_specs.pdf

В этом документе написано, что формат может использовать алгоритм Run-length encoded (RLE), если на это указывает третий байт файла (предполагается, что в сжатом TGA изображении третий байт имеет значение 9, 10 или 11 [стр. 6]).

Я имею небольшое представление о том, как RLE работает в теории. Например, последовательность символов **AAABBBBBC** после сжатия должна превратиться в **3A5B1C** или **A3B5C1**. Таким образом, алгоритм должен фиксировать количество повторяющихся символов. Что-то похожее я ожидал увидеть в TGA файле.

Чтобы получить и сравнить сжатое и несжатое TGA изображения, я воспользовался графическим редактором Paint dot NET. При сохранении TGA файла редактор позволяет включить или выключить сжатие в специальном окне, которое показано на этом фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рисунок, который я сохранил в сжатом и несжатом виде, имеет размер 50*50px и представляет собой сплошной квадрат цветом RGB(11, 12, 13), т.е. все пиксели изображения должны быть этого цвета.

Используя сласс `std::ifstream` и его метод `get()`, я смог вывести символы TGA изображения в консоль. Согласно спецификации, первые 18 байт файла всегда заняты различной информацией об изображении. Последовательность цветов пикселей рисунка начинается сразу после 18-ого байта, если в файле отсутствует цветовая карта (Color Map) и поле с названием Image ID.

**Вот что я получил:**

*Несжатое* TGA изображение:

```
1) 0
2) 0
3) 2 // <- третий байт не равен 9, 10 или 11, поэтому изображение является несжатым
4) 0
5) 0
6) 0
7) 0
8) 0
9) 0
10) 0
11) 0
12) 0
13) 50
14) 0
15) 50
16) 0
17) 24
18) 0
19) 13 // <- первый символ, описывающий цвет пикселя
20) 12
21) 11
22) 13
23) 12
24) 11
25) 13
26) 12
27) 11
28) 13
29) 12
30) 11
31) 13
32) 12
33) 11
... // и так далее
```

*Сжатое* TGA изображение:

```
1) 0
2) 0
3) 10 // <- третий байт равен 10, поэтому изображение является сжатым
4) 0
5) 0
6) 0
7) 0
8) 0
9) 0
10) 0
11) 0
12) 0
13) 50
14) 0
15) 50
16) 0
17) 24
18) 0
19) 177 // <- первый символ, описывающий цвет пикселя
20) 13
21) 12
22) 11
23) 177
24) 13
25) 12
26) 11
27) 177
28) 13
29) 12
30) 11
31) 177
32) 13
33) 12
34) 11
... // и так далее
```

В несжатом изображении после 18 символа идут значения синего, зеленого и красного цвета (BGR). Так как все пиксели рисунка имеют такой цвет, последовательность трех значений **13 12 11** много раз повторяется. В сжатом изображении много раз повторяется последовательность четырех значений **177 13 12 11**. Я не могу понять, что это значит. Результат не похож на то, что я ожидал и описывал ранее.

Мне очень хочется понять логику этого алгоритма сжатия, но на данный момент я не смог найти информацию на этот счет. Чтение спецификации и поиск в интернете пока не помог найти мне ответ на этот вопрос. Пожалуста, подскажите, где можно почитать об этом? Может быть, есть какие-нибудь статьи или книги?

Я пока не придумал, как прикрепить сюда изображения TGA формата, которые обрабатывал мой код, но, мне кажется, что это и не нужно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void ReadImage_TGA(const char* file_path_c_str);

int main()
{

    ReadImage_TGA(".../image.tga");

    return 0;
}

void ReadImage_TGA(const char* file_path_c_str)
{
    std::string file_path = file_path_c_str;

    std::ifstream file_stream;
    file_stream.open(file_path, std::ios_base::binary);

    if (file_stream.is_open() == false)
    {
        perror(("Error while opening file " + file_path).c_str());
        return;
    }

    char current_char;
    int count = 1;

    while ((bool)file_stream.get(current_char) == true)
    {
        std::cout << count << ") " << (int)current_char << std::endl;
        count++;
    }

    if (file_stream.eof())
    {
        std::cout << "End of file reached." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (file_stream.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Type error." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown error" << std::endl;
    }

    file_stream.close();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изображение кодируется по строкам, начиная с нижней. Данные хранятся в виде пакетов. Первый байт - заголовок. Если 7й бит в нем 0, то пакет содержит цвета N пикселей без сжатия, если 1 - то пакет содержит цвет пикселя, повторяющегося N раз. Число N берется как целое число в остальные 7 битах + 1.

Таким образом заголовок 177 (10110001) говорит о наличии пакета с цветом пикселя, повторяющегося 50 (00110001 + 1) раз. Получается одна строка исходного изображения. По идее, эта последовательность должна затем повторяться 50 раз.

http://www.paulbourke.net/dataformats/tga/